# Problems with writing in RStudio

Tags: cursor

When I write my code as normal in RStudio, there is always at least one space between what I have just written and where I can continue writing. If I then delete something, for example, then I delete the last letter/number despite the space. If I skip the space with my cursor keys and I am then directly at the last letter/number, I delete characters before that letter/number. I have a Mac computer without a large keyboard and I only have this problem with RStudio, not Word or other programs. I've already tried googling the problem, but I'm not even sure what to google, so I can't come up with a solution.

I tried to delete the character last written but there is always a space too many and if I skip the space with my cursor keys I'll delete the character before.

Comment: Apparently it's automatically happening whenever I write the letter combination of 'fi' ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.